# How to solve broadcast issue in Deep Learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I have an issue with my code, at broadcasting.

I got this error at Step 8:

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1062433,1) doesn't match 
the broadcast shape (1062433,2)
```

and I have this code:

Step 1: Read the data

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
```

Step 2: Split the data into training and testing sets

```
train_end_date = df['Date'].max() - pd.DateOffset(years=5)  
train_data = df[df['Date'] <= train_end_date]
test_data = df[df['Date'] > train_end_date]
```

Step 3: Normalize the data

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
cols_to_scale = ['feature1', 'feature2']  
train_data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train_data[cols_to_scale])
test_data_scaled = scaler.transform(test_data[cols_to_scale])
print("Step 3")
print("train_data_scaled", train_data_scaled.shape)
print("test_data_scaled", test_data_scaled.shape)
```

Step 4: Prepare the input sequences and labels

```
def create_sequences(data, sequence_length):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        X.append(data[i:i+sequence_length, :])  
        y.append(data[i+sequence_length, 0])  
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

sequence_length = 10  
X_train, y_train = create_sequences(train_data_scaled, sequence_length)
X_test, y_test = create_sequences(test_data_scaled, sequence_length)
print("Step 4")
print("X_train", X_train.shape)
print("y_train", y_train.shape)
print("X_test", X_test.shape)
print("y_test", y_test.shape)
```

Step 5: Build the Transformer model

```
input_shape = (sequence_length, X_train.shape[2])
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = inputs
num_layers = 2
d_model = 32
num_heads = 4
dff = 64
dropout_rate = 0.1

for _ in range(num_layers):
    x = MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=d_model)(x, x)
    x = Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    x = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
x = Dense(units=1)(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

Step 6: Compile and train the model

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=32)
```

Step 7: Evaluate the model

```
train_predictions = model.predict(X_train)
test_predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print("Step 7")
print("train_predictions at evaluation", train_predictions.shape)
print("test_predictions at evaluation", test_predictions.shape)
```

Step 8: Inverse transform the predictions to obtain the actual values - HERE IS THE ERROR

```
train_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predictions.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
test_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predictions.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
print("Step 8")
print("train_predictions after inversion", train_predictions.shape)
print("test_predictions after inversion", test_predictions.shape)
```

As asked in the comments' section, I tried to print the most significant parts of the code in order to find out where it cracks. Therefore, these are the results:

```
Step 3
train_data_scaled (1062443, 2)
test_data_scaled (308138, 2)
Step 4
X_train (1062433, 10, 2)
y_train (1062433,)
X_test (308128, 10, 2)
y_test (308128,)
33202/33202 [==============================] - 431s 13ms/step - loss: 2.1277e-05 - mae: 4.1088e-04
33202/33202 [==============================] - 203s 6ms/step
9629/9629 [==============================] - 55s 6ms/step
Step 7
train_predictions at evaluation (1062433, 1)
test_predictions at evaluation (308128, 1)
```

It definitely changed when training, but how could I solve this issue?

Thanks so much.
:D

Comment: This is a typical error when the shape of data (tensors) mismatch during one of the basic operation inside tf utility functions (in step 8, the inverse_transform). If would be helpful that you print out the shape of the I/O tensors. Especially `train_predictions` and print out more info about the `scalar : MinMaxScaler`

Comment: I don't think the output of shape of `model`, i.e. the shape of `train_predictions` equals the output shape of `scaler.transform`, i.e. the shape of `test_data_scaled`, i.e. the input shape of  the `model`. Therefore, you get the shape-mismatch error.

Comment: Step through the code line by line and check tensors shapes.

Comment: Thank you @gdlmx @stateMachine! I edited the post with the outputs.

Comment: of course, one second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the error is shape-mismatch in those tensors.

See Step 3

```py
cols_to_scale = ['feature1', 'feature2']  
train_data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train_data[cols_to_scale])
# train_data_scaled has the shape of (1062443, 2)
```

Note that the train_data has 2 features

Step 7-8

```py
train_predictions = model.predict(X_train)
# train_predictions has the shape of (1062433, 1)
train_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predictions.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
```

Note that the output data (predictions of the `model`) has only one feature.

Therefore, it throws an exception

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1062433,1) doesn't match 
the broadcast shape (1062433,2)
```

because,  [`scaler.inverse_transform()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.transform) expects the input argument to have the **same number of features** as that of `train_data_scaled`, which was used to fit it.

### Solution

I assume that the output feature and input features of the Neural Net `model` have the same meaning, because of the way you prepare them in the `create_sequences()`.

You can trick  `inverse_transform()` by [padding](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) the output tensor `train_predictions` with arbitrary values, so that train_predictions have 2 features as expected by `scaler`.

```py
import numpy as np
def padding_output(y):
    # padding y so that  new_y.shape[1] == y.shape[1] + 1
    return np.pad(y, ((0, 0), (0, 1)), 'edge')

train_predictions = padding_output( train_predictions.reshape(-1, 1) )

train_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predictions)[:,0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @gdlmx! How exactly could this be corrected ?

Comment: I'm trying with only : 

train_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predictions)
test_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predictions)

Comment: @AriadneR. You simply need to think about what is the meaning of the single **output feature** in  the output data tensor `*_predictions`. If it (the output feature) has the same physical meaning as the **input features** `['feature1', 'feature2']`, you can repeat it and feed them into `inverse_transform`.

Comment: @AriadneR. In most cases, the output of such neural net model does NOT have the same meaning (statistical characteristics) of the input. You should NOT scale it with the same parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm trying to figure out all the details based on what you have told me and come back with a proper answer. thanks so much! @gdlmx

Comment: @AriadneR. I have a further look into your model. It seems that the output and input features  do have the same meaning. So I update my answer with a solution.